# Do cycle graphs embed isometrically in spheres?

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, embeddings, metric-embeddings

I recently came across, what seems to be a folklore.  Namely, that cycle graphs embeds isometrically into spheres $S^n(r)$, for some $n\in \mathbb{N}_+$ and some $r>0$.  However, I could not track down a proof or paper on the subject.

Is this actually true?

Comment: What are the def's and details?

Comment: What do you mean by "cycle graph"? In the terminology I'm used to, these are just the graphs $C_n$. But then the result is trivial, isn't it?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I don't fully see it yet tbh, since to me it seems one needs to rescale there unit sphere...

Comment: @Justin_other_PhD Cycle graphs may contain points at distance $>\pi$, so an isometric imbedding shouldn't be possible. Maybe I am understanding wrong

Comment: @SaúlRM Ah you're right; I modified it to by an isometry into some sphere $S^n(r)$ for some $r>0$ and some $n\in \mathbb{N}_+$ (or equivalently an isometric embedding into the $n$-sphere with Riemannian metric rescaled by a constant)

Comment: But any cyclic graph with $n$ vertices is isometric to a circumference of radius $n/(2\pi)$, right? So in that case it should be trivial (in fact spheres of radius $n/(2\pi)$ are the only ones which will allow the imbedding). In what I say I am considering cycle graphs as CW-complexes of dimension $1$ with edges of length $1$

Comment: Ah, I was thinking of them as discrete metric spaces; but I guess the discrete version isometrically embeds in the CW complex version.

Comment: I see. Even considering the discrete version, for $n\geq4$ the cycle $C_n$ only imbeds in spheres of radius $n/(2\pi)$: this is because for any two points $p,q,r$ of the sphere, $d(p,q)+d(p,r)=d(q,r)$ implies that $p,q,r$ are in some geodesic, due to, for example, the spherical cosine theorem